# Getting an error when combining two reducers using combineReducers()

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux

I'm trying to create separate reducers for different React components. This is the code:

store.tsx:

```
const store = createStore(rootReducer, composeWithDevTools());
```

root.reducers.tsx:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import mainReducer from './main.reducers';
import profileReducers from './components/Profile/Profile.reducers';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    mainReducer,
    profileReducers,
});

export default rootReducer;
```

main.reducers.tsx:

```
<...>
function mainReducer(state = initialState, action: AnyAction) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case HOME_PAGE_MOVIES_ADDED:
            return {
                ...state,
                homePageMovies: action.homePageMovies,
            };
        case MOVIE_SELECTED:
            return {
                ...state,
                selectedMovie: action.selectedMovie,
            };

        default:
            return state;

export default mainReducer;
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof mainReducer>;
```

profile.reducers.tsx:

```
interface mainState {
    selectedCategory: boolean;
}

const initialState: mainState = {
    selectedCategory: false,
};

function profileReducers(state = initialState, action: AnyAction) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case CATEGORY_SELECTED:
            return {
                ...state,
                selectedCategory: action.selectedCategory,
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default profileReducers;
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof profileReducers>;
```

When I try to render UI, I get following error:
[image]

[image]

I get this error once I replace `mainReducer` by `rootReducer` at `*/store.tsx` > `const store = createStore(mainReducer, composeWithDevTools());`.

What am i missing? Thanks!

Comment: What are the errors? What makes you think it's related to `combineReducers`? Please edit the post to include the full error message(s) and associated code stacktrace(s).

Comment: I've updated the post including the error message. It's complaining about the code that worked fine before replacing `mainReducer` by `rootReducer` at `*/store.tsx > const store = createStore(mainReducer, composeWithDevTools());`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems prior to using the `combineReducers` function to create/merge/expand your redux store's state tree you had just the single reducer.

```
const store = createStore(mainReducer, composeWithDevTools());
```

As such the state that `mainReducer` handled ***was*** your app's state.

```
const favoriteMoviesAll = useSelector(
  (state: RootState) => state.homePageMovies
);
```

When you start expanding the state tree you are now nesting reducers under specific keys.

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  mainReducer,
  profileReducers,
});

const store = createStore(rootReducer, composeWithDevTools());
```

Now the root `state` is an object with `mainReducer` and `profileReducers` properties. `state.homePageMovies` is undefined.

```
const favoriteMoviesAll = useSelector(
  (state: RootState) => state.homePageMovies // undefined
);
```

Now `favoriteMoviesAll` is also undefined and can't access any `slice` method.

```
const favoriteMovies = favoriteMoviesAll.slice(0, 19); // throws error!
```

The same previous state that was `state.homePageMovies` is now nested deeper in `state.mainReducer.homePageMovies`.

```
const favoriteMoviesAll = useSelector(
  (state: RootState) => state.mainReducer.homePageMovies
);
```

Since this is the way `react-redux` works, and the naming convention for the reducer functions is `<state-area>Reducer` it's common to rename the reducers being passed to `combineReducers` to give them more readable names that make sense in a state tree.

Example:

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  movies: mainReducer,
  profile: profileReducers,
});
```

...

```
const favoriteMoviesAll = useSelector(
  (state: RootState) => state.movies.homePageMovies
);
```

Comment: You can explain the solution so perfectly, amazing! I’m surprised you are both so experienced and still have the ability to explain the concepts that are simple to you in such a clear manner. After reading your explicit comment the issue and the fix needed were clear to me, and I was able to fix the defect quickly (although without your guidance I would probably stay stuck since I had no idea what I did wrong). Much appreciated!

Comment: @rumon Welcome, glad to help. Thank you, those are very kind words. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

In selector you need use:

> state.[nameReducer].[data what you want]

If i good understand what you trying to do you need:

> state.mainReducer.homePageMovies